# How to change ownership of pointer in C++'11?

Tags: c++, std, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I would like to store a pointer to my native window instance using `unique_ptr<NativeWindow>` so that it is guaranteed to be freed when `Window` object goes out of scope.

```
// This would be maintained by a window manager
unique_ptr<Window> window;

void Foo() {
    NativeWindow *pNativeWindow = createNativeWindow();
    window = new Window(pNativeWindow);
}

// ...

class Window {
private:
    unique_ptr<NativeWindow> _nativeWindow;
public:
    inline NativeWindow& GetNativeWindow() {
        return *_nativeWindow;
    }

// ...

Window::Window(NativeWindow&& nativeWindow)
    : _nativeWindow(std::move(nativeWindow))
{
}
```

I am having a hard time understanding the move semantics and would find it easier to learn from this example. If this were vanilla pointers I would be fine, but I am trying to understand the new way!

Comment: `unique_ptr<T> second = first;`

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, I am getting the following error message with the above code:

    `Error 1 error C2664: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr(std::nullptr_t) throw()' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'NativeWindow' to 'std::nullptr_t'`

Comment: @H2CO3 Not `unique_ptr<T> second = std::move(first);`?

Comment: This will not compile: `window = new Window(pNativeWindow);`. It should be `window.reset(new Window(pNativeWindow));` or (in C++14) `window = std::make_unique<Window>(pNativeWindow));`. And it will still not compile because of other problems :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The docs at cppreference.com claim that the assignment operator transfers ownership, so I was wrong in that initialization doesn't work, but `unique_ptr<T> second; second = first;` should.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at just using assignment instead of `std::move`. Should I be using `shared_ptr<NativeWindow> nativeWindow = createNativeWindow();`?

Comment: @H2CO3 No, it still won't work. `unique_ptr` will not transfer ownership unless you explicitly `std::move` or `.release()` the managed pointer. If it did what you claim, we'd not have any need for it, `auto_ptr` would've been enough.

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks for the clarification. Then what does "Transfers ownership of the object pointed to by r to `*this` as if by calling `reset(r.release())` followed by an assignment from `std::forward<E>(r.get_deleter())`" mean in the docs [(link)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D)? Or am I misinterpreting the documentation and the rvalue reference overload only takes place when you `std::move`? Or is the documentation incorrect?

Comment: @H2CO3 Read the note following that ... *Note that unique_ptr's assignment operator only accepts xvalues* You're missing the fact that the type of the paramter for `operator=` is `unique_ptr&&`

Comment: @Praetorian Yes, yes, that's what I'm asking about. So basically that overload can only be accessed using `std::move()`, is it that?

Comment: @H2CO3 Well, it can be accessed whenever the argument is an xvalue; typically it'd be done via `std::move`

Comment: @Praetorian I just noticed your comment regarding `auto_ptr`. Is this still in commission then? I thought it was replaced in favour of the new ones :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Window` constructor should be taking a `NativeWindow *`, not `NativeWindow&&`.

```
Window::Window(NativeWindow* nativeWindow)
    : _nativeWindow(nativeWindow)
{
}
```

That should work, but I suggest you change the parameter to `unique_ptr<NativeWindow>` instead. This makes it clear that the `Window` object is assuming ownership of the `NativeWindow` argument.

```
Window::Window(std::unique_ptr<NativeWindow> nativeWindow)
    : _nativeWindow(std::move(nativeWindow))
{
}
```

Comment: Ideally, `CreateNativeWindow` should return `unique_ptr<NativeWindow>` as well.

Comment: Okay I have changed my code to this, and am now returning `unique_ptr<NativeWindow>` from my factory function, but I am still getting a compile error. I have `window.reset(new Window(nativeWindow));` which says `error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'`. I have changed the constructor to `Window::Window(std::unique_ptr<NativeWindow> nativeWindow)` as suggested above.

Comment: @LeaHayes Sounds like you're attempting to copy the `unique_ptr` somewhere. If your `createNativeWindow` function is now returning a `unique_ptr`, you'll need to `move` it when calling the constructor. `window.reset(new Window(std::move(nativeWindow)));`

Comment: Yes, that did it, compiles fine now :) So `std::move` is needed quite a lot in C++'11 it would seem.

Comment: @LeaHayes It's needed when you want to indicate some object can be moved from. In this case you could avoid one call to it by using `window.reset(new Window(createNativeWindow()));` (In response to your comment above) `auto_ptr` is deprecated.